# Is there a module to show photos on Drupal site that come from Facebook user profile/Facebook page, like Wordpress Fotobook

Tags: 7, media, feeds, importing-exporting, social-network

Wordpress Fotobook plugin will show photos from a user's Facebook profile (assuming the user has set the appropriate permissions for them to be made visible, and that suitable Facebook App settings and id have been setup).

I wondered if there was an equivalent module for Drupal?

I would prefer a module that doesn't locally copy the photos onto the site but rather links to the original photos on Facebook. This preference is be efficient with bandwidth, storage space, and backup. Effectively, I'm looking for something that makes Rvisible album photos in a similar way to RSS feed (doesn't have to be exactly the same format as RSS but the same kind of idea whereby the original content is not copied.)

I am developing sites for two friends who actively use Facebook but want photos on their own sites. With the Drupal 7 Media module, multi-image batch uploading is very capably handled in Drupal, however this still requires double effort to upload photos both to their profiles and their sites.

Let me know if a module is available. I am considering writing one myself, learning from Fotobook, but didn't want to duplicate effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sandbox project: http://drupal.org/sandbox/kcmanc87/1591712
And maybe Feeds would work. I will try both soon.

Comment: +1 I will check it out and make it accepted. I have unaccepted my own answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

Kept this open for a while but there has been no answer so I guess not. So, another module for my to do list to write, once I am fluent in writing modules and the Facebook APIs.